# Scaling 3D-Points depending on Groundtruth

Tags: logic, 3d

I generated points of a trajectory of a plane, like:

$$
\begin{array}{lcr}
\text{x} & \text{y} & \text{z} \\
\hline
0.396950& -0.199959& -0.000336\\
0.122995& -0.199975& -0.000012\\
-0.136482& -0.199928& -0.000218\\
-0.341374& -0.200314& -0.000229\\
-0.535641& -0.199760& -0.000294\\
-0.739213& -0.199757& -0.000681\\
-0.947670& -0.198823& -0.001423\\
-1.138527& -0.197710& -0.001864\\
-1.317643& -0.197096& -0.001376\\
-1.455360& -0.196546& -0.001692
\end{array}
$$

And I have the real ground-truth of the plane:

$$
\begin{array}{lcr}
\text{x} & \text{y} & \text{z} \\
\hline
7.3695250e+005&  4.8777822e+005& -1.5184991e+006\\
7.3451058e+005&  4.8616195e+005& -1.5201820e+006\\
7.3438841e+005&  4.8608109e+005& -1.5202660e+006\\
7.3426624e+005&  4.8600022e+005& -1.5203500e+006\\
7.3414406e+005&  4.8591935e+005& -1.5204339e+006\\
7.3402188e+005&  4.8583848e+005& -1.5205179e+006\\
7.3389968e+005&  4.8575760e+005& -1.5206018e+006\\
7.3377748e+005&  4.8567672e+005& -1.5206858e+006\\
7.3365528e+005&  4.8559584e+005& -1.5207697e+006
\end{array}
$$

Now I want to scale my points to see how they are compared to the real ones.

The first 2 of both lists can be used for scaling because the first to where generated when the plane was at the first two points of the groundtruth. (I hope that was understandable)

Anyone have a hint how to scale my points?

Comment: Could you explain your tag choice?

Comment: @user37238 I couldnt find one that matched my problem.